# clicking cancel button showing value of another textfield

Tags: javascript, php, magento

we are using magento marketplace multivendor site.

we gave an option for vendor to update the product details in frontend.

we are using this code for updating the price. its working fine.

**Phtml**

```
<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "price[]" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = ""/>

<input type="hidden" name="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" />

<p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>

<button id="price_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="update" onclick="updateFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>

<button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
```

**JS**

```
<script>

function hideResetPrice(product_id,priceold) { 

var qtyId='#price_'+ product_id; 
var currprice='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#price_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#price_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valueprice="#valueprice_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#price_reset_button_"+ product_id; 


$wk_jq(valueprice).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currprice).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}



function showFieldPrice(product_id)
        {

            var qtyId='#price_'+ product_id;

            var editLink="#price_edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var valueprice="#valueprice_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton="#price_update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton="#price_reset_button_"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).show();
            $wk_jq(valueprice).hide();

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            return false;


        }


function updateFieldPrice(product_id) 
{ 
var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id; 
var currprice='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldPrice/')?>'; 
$price = $wk_jq(priceId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currprice).val($price); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 
parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

we are using following code for special price. **initially we edit price value. than once we enter some number in special price and if we click on cancel button of special price, its showing previously updated value of "price"** not special price.

**Phtml**

```
<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "specialprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name = "specialprice[]" value = "<?php echo $products->getSpecialPrice(); ?>" style = ""/>

<p id="updatedspecialprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p> 
<br/> 

<button id="specialprice_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="update" onclick="updateFieldSpecialPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;"  >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>
<button id="specialprice_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetSpecialPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" >


<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>                                                       

</span>
```

**JS**

```
 function hideResetSpecialPrice(product_id,priceold) {

                var qtyId='#specialprice_'+ product_id;
                var currspecialprice='#curr_'+ product_id;
                var editLink="#specialprice_edit_link_"+ product_id;
                var updateButton="#specialprice_update_button_"+ product_id;
                var valuespecialprice="#valuespecialprice_"+ product_id;
                var resetButton="#specialprice_reset_button_"+ product_id;
                $wk_jq(valuespecialprice).show(); 
                $wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currspecialprice).val()); 
                $wk_jq(editLink).show(); 




            }

    function showFieldSpecialPrice(product_id)
            {

                var qtyId='#specialprice_'+ product_id;

                var editLink="#specialprice_edit_link_"+ product_id;
                var valueprice="#valuespecialprice_"+ product_id;
                var updateButton="#specialprice_update_button_"+ product_id;
                var resetButton="#specialprice_reset_button_"+ product_id;

                $wk_jq(qtyId).show();
                $wk_jq(valueprice).hide();

                $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
                $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
                $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
                $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

                return false;

           }



    function updateFieldSpecialPrice(product_id) 
    { 
    var priceId = '#specialprice_'+ product_id; 
    var updatedqty = '#updatedspecialprice_'+ product_id; 
    var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldSpecialPrice/')?>'; 
    $price = $wk_jq(priceId).val(); 
    new Ajax.Request(url, { 
    method: 'post', 
    parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price}, 
    onComplete: function (transport) { 
    //alert(transport.responseText); 
    jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 
    } 
    }); 
    }
```

**Local Code**

```
<?php $attribute = $products->getResource()->getAttribute('local');?>
<?php if($attribute):?>
<?php $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($products); ?>

<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "local_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "price[]" value = "<?php echo $attribute_value; ?>" style = ""/>
<?php endif; ?>


<input type="hidden" name="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getLocal(); ?>" />  

<p id="updatedlocal_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>
<button id="local_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="update" onclick="updateFieldLocal('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>

<button id="local_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetLocal('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
</span>
```

**JS**

```
function hideResetLocal(product_id,localold) { 

var qtyId='#local_'+ product_id; 
var currlocal='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#local_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#local_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valuelocal="#valuelocal_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#local_reset_button_"+ product_id; 


$wk_jq(valuelocal).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currlocal).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}



function showFieldLocal(product_id)
        {

            var qtyId='#local_'+ product_id;

            var editLink="#local_edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var valuelocal="#valuelocal_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton="#local_update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton="#local_reset_button_"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).show();
            $wk_jq(valuelocal).hide();

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            return false;


        }




function updateFieldLocal(product_id) 
{ 
var localId = '#local_'+ product_id; 
var currlocal='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedlocal_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldLocal/')?>'; 
$local = $wk_jq(localId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currlocal).val($local); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 

parameters: {id: product_id, local: $local}, 
//parameters: {id: product_id, local: $local}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this hidden filed for special price

```
<input type="hidden" name="specialcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="specialcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getSpecialPrice(); ?>" />
```

update js

```
function hideResetSpecialPrice(product_id,priceold) {

                var qtyId='#specialprice_'+ product_id;
                var currspecialprice='#specialcurr_'+ product_id;
                var editLink="#specialprice_edit_link_"+ product_id;
                var updateButton="#specialprice_update_button_"+ product_id;
                var valuespecialprice="#valuespecialprice_"+ product_id;
                var resetButton="#specialprice_reset_button_"+ product_id;
                $wk_jq(valuespecialprice).show(); 
                $wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currspecialprice).val()); 
                $wk_jq(editLink).show(); 




            }

    function showFieldSpecialPrice(product_id)
            {

                var qtyId='#specialprice_'+ product_id;

                var editLink="#specialprice_edit_link_"+ product_id;
                var valueprice="#valuespecialprice_"+ product_id;
                var updateButton="#specialprice_update_button_"+ product_id;
                var resetButton="#specialprice_reset_button_"+ product_id;

                $wk_jq(qtyId).show();
                $wk_jq(valueprice).hide();

                $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
                $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
                $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
                $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

                return false;

           }



    function updateFieldSpecialPrice(product_id) 
    { 
    var priceId = '#specialprice_'+ product_id; 
    var currspecialprice='#specialcurr_'+ product_id;
    var updatedqty = '#updatedspecialprice_'+ product_id; 
    var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldSpecialPrice/')?>'; 
    $price = $wk_jq(priceId).val();
    $wk_jq(currspecialprice).val($price); 
    new Ajax.Request(url, { 
    method: 'post', 
    parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price}, 
    onComplete: function (transport) { 
    //alert(transport.responseText); 
    jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 
    } 
    }); 
    }
```

Comment: it showng blank when we click on cancel button under special price

Comment: working for special price, but yearday i added local, now same problem with price and local. i will update the local code in question

Comment: please check now : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434513/magento-site-clicking-cancel-is-changing-some-other-text-field-value